# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405. Method not allowed. This is happening for Cross Origin requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, cors

I have an Angular 2 app as a front end from where I am hitting my backend API in C# for a POST request. Since the request being cross origin, the browser is converting my POST method to OPTIONS method.

To tackle this, I put `config.EnableCors();` in webapiconfig.cs file in my backend API but it doesn't help.
Also, tried adding this in web.config:-

```
add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Doesn't work at all.
In Browser header it shows->

```
Request URL:http://localhost:4883/api/employeeapi
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address:[::1]:4883
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution by adding below piece of code in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
}
```